# How do I keep OSX from catching/interpreting the bash keyboard-shortcuts?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, bash, terminal

When I open a bash terminal in OSX and then type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to got back one word it instead opens the find dialog? Many of the other key-bindings have similar problems. How can I change this?

Comment: Related discussion in this question: http://superuser.com/questions/139444/better-terminal-program-for-snow-leopard-os-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences->Settings check the "Option as Meta Key" checkbox at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>rightarrow</kbd>.

You have the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button one to the left of <kbd>alt</kbd> (option), this does everything in the terminal just like it would on a regular qwerty keyboard(windows, linux).

You can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> shortcut in the rest of your osx applications for a lot the same functions like end of line <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and beginning of line <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>.

A very similar question was asked on stackoverflow and it has some really excellent answers already.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81272/mac-os-x-terminal-move-cursor-word-by-word